# Does sleeping produce heat and use up water in the body?

Tags: water, body-temperature, fever, dehydration, naps

Several times, after an afternoon nap, I noticed that I was severely dehydrated and had a slight fever. Before the nap, I was feeling normal but tired. After the nap, the temperature went away and after drinking a lot of water the thirst also went away.

I have read that sleep uses up more energy than watching tv. So could it be that using up the energy produces heat and uses water?